# using if statement directly in bash prompt?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am not sure if this is even possible directly. But I am trying to get the current temperature of the CPU using:

```
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
```

I want to pipe the output of the same command using echo to a if statement to carry out a shutdown if the temperature is higher then 70000. (Output of the command needs to be divided by 1000 to temperature in centigrade).

something like

```
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) | if $cpu -gt 70000 then shutdown fi
```

I am trying to do this to stop my pi from overheating. I will schedule a cronjob that checks every 15 minutes for CPU temperature of my Pi and shut it down if it is over 70.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your last command is *almost* correct, but the syntax is wrong.  Corrected version:

```
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp); if [ "$cpu" -gt 70000 ]; then shutdown; fi
```

Or, shorter,

```
cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp); [ "$cpu" -gt 70000 ] && shutdown
```

Or, shorter,

```
[ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -gt 70000 ] && shutdown
```

The issue with your command (apart from the syntax of the `if`-statement) is that you use a pipeline. The right hand side of a pipeline (your `if` statement) should read from the left hand side of the pipeline (your variable assignment).  A variable assignment does not produce any output, and your `if`-statement does not consume any input.  Furthermore, the value of `$cpu` is unknown on the right hand side of the pipe as the two parts of the pipeline are executed concurrently.

For a cron job, the following may be a better formulation of the command:

```
[ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 70000 ] || shutdown
```

This ensures that the command exits successfully even if the temperature is low. The `[ ... -gt 70000 ] && shutdown` variation would return a non-zero exit from the `[ ... ]` test for low temperatures, which would make `cron` think the job failed.

Note also that this requires that the crontab is using `bash` as the shell to run the jobs, or the `$(<...)` syntax may not work properly.  You may change `$(<...)` to `$(cat ...)` or you may set `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of the crontab. Also, to run `shutdown`, you likely need root privileges.

Comment: Hey I truly appreciate this. But it does not seem to work in the crontab. Here is the grep of the syslog:

Oct 30 00:22:02 hostname CRON[8298]: (user1) CMD ([ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 7000 ] || shutdown now)
Oct 30 00:22:05 hostname CRON[8294]: (user1) MAIL (mailed 64 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)

Comment: I tried this with sudo crontab -e also to launch it as root but doesn't work.

Comment: @ParthManiar See added bit at the end. Let me know what the email to root says if it fails.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with sudo poweroff in crontab of root and it worked. I do see an error after the first half of the command which is the output of temperature digits. I want to run multiple tasks: send an email before shutting down, stopping services and unmount drives before shutting down. Something like 

I am testing with 7000 as it is below the current temperature.

[ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 7000 ] || /path_to_bash_script/1 >> /path_to_file/1.txt || cat /path_to_file/1.txt | mail -s "CRITICAL_SHUTDOWN_INITIATED" name@email.com || sudo poweroff

Comment: @ParthManiar I would suggest that you put everything in a script by itself and schedule _that_ script with crontab. That would make it much easier. Scheduling things that are only one or two commands directly with crontab is ok, but as soon as you have three or more commands and some kind of conditional execution of things, then it's very much easier to just write that in a shell script and schedule that instead. This would make it easier to maintain the script without bothering about crontab.  Also, if you run the cron job as root, you won't need `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you very much. My post should have given an idea that I am novice at this. But I'm going to try and post that. I'm using && instead of || which is allowing the script to continue. I hope that good. :)

Comment: This is what I've used finally - [ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 70000 ] || /user1/1 >> /user1/1.txt && cat /user1/1.txt | mail -s "EMERGENCY_SHUTDOWN_INITIATED" name@domain.com && sudo service apache2 graceful-stop && sudo umount /mnt/nxtcld &&  sudo poweroff

Comment: @ParthManiar As I said, I would definitely put that in a nicely formatted shell script with a proper multi-line `if`-`then`-`else`.

Comment: Well it sucks to be honest because the script doesn't seem to work. I will try the file thing after some rest :) Thank you for all your guidance :)

Comment: Could you kindly answer why  [ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 70000 ] && echo yes .. gives output of YES (echo succeeds) but  [ "$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)" -le 7000 ] && echo yes -- does not go to the echo command. it's opposite of what I'm expecting the script to do.

Comment: I've replaced -le with -gt